# Android Audiotrack clicking noise since Android 4 ICS

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, audiotrack

i have also a piano keyboard integrated in my app. I encountered a problem with audiotrack, when setting the **playbackRate** with `setPlayBackRate(...)`. To get the next half-tone on the keyboard i change the playback rate with this formula:

```
int playbackRate = (int) (Math.pow(2.0, (1.0/12.0)) * 44100);

audioTrack.setPlaybackRate(playbackRate);
```

this works well on `Android 2.2.1` and `2.3.5`, but on `4.0/4.1.2` (Galaxy Nexus) i get a clicking noise when playing the sound.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same problem, since ICS it sound laggy but on 2.3.x on devices 10 times less powerful it is fluid. Have you found a workaround? I tried modifing Thread priorities without success.

Comment: Hi, yes i fixed it. It was so simple. multiply the minbuffersize when initialising audiotrack by 2, so minBufferSize * 2. And it works like a charm :)
You can get the minBufferSize from static audiotrack method getminbuffersize(...)

Comment: @sNore thanks a lot  :)